# How to change line chart background color on charts_flutter plugin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am using charts_flutter to create a line chart, but i have difficulty to change the color of the charts. the background color follow the themes background color, i wany change to white background.

[image]

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72231347/354277) to the same question. @Yozmo 's answer below doesn't work for me, there's no "color" property on a chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ColorUtil method from dart for doing that:

```
color: chart.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.white)
```