# Set background color in flutter chart

Tags: android, flutter, charts

I am using charts_flutter to build a bar chart, but having a hard time setting the background color. The char is working fine, but I cannot seem to find the option to set the background color, which now for some reason is black (nowhere in the code the word "black" appears) Here's what I have so far:

```
/// Bar chart example
// EXCLUDE_FROM_GALLERY_DOCS_START
import 'dart:math';
// EXCLUDE_FROM_GALLERY_DOCS_END
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SimpleBarChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series<dynamic, String>> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  SimpleBarChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate = false});

  // EXCLUDE_FROM_GALLERY_DOCS_START
  // This section is excluded from being copied to the gallery.
  // It is used for creating random series data to demonstrate animation in
  // the example app only.
  factory SimpleBarChart.withRandomData() {
    return new SimpleBarChart(_createRandomData());
  }

  /// Create random data.
  static List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createRandomData() {
    final random = new Random();

    final data = [
      new OrdinalSales('2014', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2015', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2016', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2017', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2018', random.nextInt(100)),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
  // EXCLUDE_FROM_GALLERY_DOCS_END

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
    );
  }
}

/// Sample ordinal data type.
class OrdinalSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  OrdinalSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

[image: That's what it looks like right now]

Any advice?

Comment: It could be taking the color from the MaterialApp theme. Have you tried wrapping it with a `Container` widget and giving it a different color?

Comment: @JoãoSoares that's exactly it. Wrapped it in a container with the color property set to ```Colors.green``` and it changed. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I've added an answer below to help other users looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `BarChart` with a `Container` and give it a color.

```
return Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: new charts.BarChart(
    seriesList,
    animate: animate,
  ),
);
```